# If I configure a default route for a switch, will it override the routing of the existing traffic?

Tags: routing, switching

In this instance it's a Extreme managed switch, but I guess this would apply on others too.

Basically, I noticed we couldn't ping the switch, and eventually found this was down to the fact the switch itself didn't know where to route the packets in responding to the ping request.

Now I've add a static route for the monitoring network, but I'm wondering if I should add a default gateway as well, as one isn't currently set. However, if I add one will it effect the 'switched' traffic that is already travelling over the network normally, or is the gateway and routes defined on the switch only for the management traffic of the switch itself?

Comment: This depends on your switch configuration. If ports are pure layer 2 (switching), it won't affect traffic, but if the switch also provides routing functions (layer 3) it could affect traffic.

Comment: Want to put that as an answer @TeunVink ? If I get nothing better, that explains enough for me to figure out the rest.

Comment: Also, remember that a default route is a route of last resort. Any more-specific routes will be used before a default route. You cannot override a specific route with a default route.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on your switch configuration. If ports are pure layer 2 (switching), it won't affect traffic, but if the switch also provides routing functions (layer 3) it could affect traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Always specific route will have priority over default route ..

**For example**

If router is configured with default route and specific route entry . Router has priority to check specific route entry first then after it will check default route . Always specific route entry will have priority on default route entry .